# IE9 “tearing” background images behind scrolling blocks with background transparency

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, transparency, scrollbar

I've made a design that uses a static auto-scrolling block with a transparent background over parent block with a background image. In IE9, scrolling causes the parent background image to "tear" instead of remaining fixed like on the other A-level browsers. Does this problem sound familiar?

In case I am not explaining this correctly, [see an example on the live site](http://kintespace.com/p_robert_thurman0.html). This example should show you one vertical scroll bar inside of the layout. Moving this bar to scroll will cause the "tearing" in IE9. (Note: that I'm using the jQuery Color plugin---which might cause the problem. It is also possible that IE requires z-order and/or absolute/relative CSS positioning---which would be rather inconvenient.)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the inline style of background-color: rgba(0, 102, 51, 0.5) from #PresentationFlow with the dev tools made the problem dissapearfor me.

Is that the color plugin maybe?

UPDATE: One solution might be to add the transparent background to #PresentationOverflowContainer instead. you need to remove some padding but then it should look o

Answer (score 0):

I would try wrapping #PresentationFlow in a div, and put the background-color on that div.

```
<div id="wrapper" style="background-color: rgba(0, 102, 51, 0.5)">
  <div id="PresentationFlow"> <!-- overflow: auto -->
  </div>
</div>
```